# Get Azure Storage Blob File Size using Azure Cli

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

Does anyone know the Azure CLI command to get the size of a file in azure blob storage?
I see that in properties, there is length - but I need the file size in GB or TB.

Comment: The length is the actual size in bytes. You need to divide by 1024 for KiB or by 1024² for MiB or by 1024³ for GiB, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below command and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list-examples) as below:

```
az storage blob list --account-name xx --container-name yy
```

xx- name of storage account

yy- name of container

[image]

If kb then divide by 1024, if MiB then 1024², if GiB then 1024³

You can get the Size of Blob by clicking on the blob like below:

[image]

You can also find the size of the blob by clicking on the properties on left pane and click on calculate size as below:

[image]